# Include an External Project in my CMake Proejct

Tags: cmake

I need to include some components from an [external project](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-models) into my cmake project. More specifically, I need to be able to use models and geometries in this repo.

I have cloned the repo and built it using the general cmake build procedure:

```
cd clonedproj/
mkdir build && cd build/
cmake ../ && make
```

However, no **config.cmake** file is generated. Since this repo has a [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-models/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), I assume that there is a way (e.g. `find_packag()`) to include the required components, without copying each of them into the my own project. How can I do so?

p.s. The [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-models/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) does not have any executable. Instead it mostly uses `install` command.

Comment: There are no executables or libraries, but a collection of resource files. How these resources are supposed to be used in your CMakeLists?

Comment: That is actually my question. 
I am using a library from the same developers, called [opensim](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-core). In opensim there is a class, called [`Model()`](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-core/blob/eec47945dde3f2c0491ec93f818b13f06f9e10d5/OpenSim/Simulation/Model/Model.h). When you instantiate a `Model`, you can use one of those resource files, e.g. `Model("arm26.osim");`. However, the class needs to have access to the geometry files, too. And my question is how I can provide access to all these resource files, in my project?